# Show products by category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This sounds as an easy question, but I couldn't find the right answer yet.

I want all my products on my WooCommerce products page, but sorted by category. Like this:

```
    Category 01 title
        - products of category 01

    Category 02 title
        - products of category 02

    Category 03 title
        - products of category 03
```

I already found this code:
[question 139196](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139196/display-all-products-by-category-with-woocommerce), but that's more case specific. I'm looking for a more general solution. How to alter the main product page (archive-product.php) with the product loop (content-product.php) so to show products in their category?

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase my question clearly, I thought this was a very common request. Apparently, WooCommerce has a paid plugin for this exact function, called 'Nested Category Layout'. But it would have been great to hard code it into a theme.

Comment: Your answer is `the_posts` filter and `usort()`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll look into that and report back.

Comment: I ended up using the solution from the link I posted in my question. Only sorting by tag doesn't seem to work, still working on that.